# How to call the function, if the count reaches the limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps and i am placing the map markers using the array `locations`, now i want to call the function `clearMarkers()` if the `i==26`

How can i do this?

code:

```
var markers = [];
var map;
var india = new google.maps.LatLng(21.9200,77.9000);
var image = 'images/pushpins/set1.png';

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: india
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
  drop();
}

function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var city = locations[i][0];
    var pro_cat = locations[i][1];
    addMarkerWithTimeout(locations[i][2], i * 500);  
    getCity(city,pro_cat, i * 500);
  }
if (i==26){
    clearMarkers();
  }
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      optimized: false,
      //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    }));
  }, timeout);
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
  document.getElementById('order_list').innerHTML = "";
}

function getCity(city_name, product_cat, timeout){
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  var writecity = document.createTextNode(city_name+', '+product_cat);
  document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(writecity);
  document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }, timeout);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Here i am using the for loop to call the function but it is not working

```
 function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          if (i==26){
             clearMarkers();
          }
    var city = locations[i][0];
    var pro_cat = locations[i][1];
    addMarkerWithTimeout(locations[i][2], i * 500);  
    getCity(city,pro_cat, i * 500);    
  }
}
```

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides there is nothing in console

Comment: Move the `if (i==26) { ... }` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I did, but still not working.

Comment: What is not working? Is the `clearMarkers` function called? Does `i` even reach 26? Use your console to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement is outside loop so the `i` variable is not set and comparison to 26 will always return false unless you have global `i` variable. Change your drop function into:

```
function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var city = locations[i][0];
    var pro_cat = locations[i][1];
    addMarkerWithTimeout(locations[i][2], i * 500);  
    getCity(city,pro_cat, i * 500);
    if (i==26){
       clearMarkers();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem you expierience however is a bit different. You place the markers after your main function is processed. Therefore nothing will be cleared. If you remove `window.setTimout` in `addMarkerWithTimeout` it should work.

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    optimized: false,
    //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  }));
}
```